# Can I make use of mms resizing in Android in my app?

Tags: android, video, xamarin, compression, mms

I am trying to send a video from my app to a server, but we are concerned about the time and data it will take to send the video. We'd like to compress/resize before sending to the server.

I know in Android, when I go to send a video in the messaging app, it asks to resize the video before attaching. Can I call this functionality from my app?

Some notes:

- We are using Xamarin, if that changes your answer. But if you provide a native answer, I'll most likely be able to figure it out.
- We have ruled out ffmpeg due to licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to send MMS in Xamarin.Android

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
sendIntent.SetClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
sendIntent.PutExtra("address", "1213123123");
sendIntent.PutExtra("sms_body", "if you are sending text");

File file1 = new File("mFileName");
if(file1.Exists())
{
    //File Exist
}
Uri uri = Uri.FromFile(file1);
sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uri);
sendIntent.SetType("video/*");
StartActivity(sendIntent);
```